# Stop emacs treating touchpad scrolling like C-g in minibuffer

Tags: mouse, isearch

I have a ThinkPad with a trackpad, and emacs exits from C-s and also from interactive replace using M-%, whenever I brush my hand over the trackpad while touch-typing - which happens far too often. With my previous laptop I worked around this problem by disabling the trackpad completely, but I can't do that here because the trackpad is an important fallback for when my erratic Bluetooth mouse stops working. How can I make C-s and M-% ignore touchpad scrolling?

**UPDATE:** It's not caused by mouse movement as I originally thought, but by mouse scrolling, or something even more obscure. From `C-h l` I can see that emacs is interpreting my brushing the touchpad as mouse-4/5/6/7, so I've tried

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") (lambda () (interactive)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") (lambda () (interactive)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-6>") (lambda () (interactive)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-7>") (lambda () (interactive)))
```

but that doesn't fix the problem, it just stops emacs complaining.

Comment: Depending on your OS, you may be able to disable the trackpad *only while typing*; that is, when a key is pressed, the trackpad is disabled for a second (or so) after the key is pressed.

Comment: That doesn't really help because I might stop to think for an indeterminate period of time.

Comment: Is the problem that the mouse *moves* while Emacs is getting input from the minibuffer, or that the laptop touchpad is *clicking*? Moving the mouse shouldn't cause this, but clicking (say, in a buffer) would cause something like this.

Comment: Regarding `M-%`, is the problem when entering the search query and replacement text, or only at the “query replacing …” prompt? Are you running Emacs in a terminal or a GUI, which version, and on which OS? Type `C-s`, then move the mouse just enough to exit incremental search, and type `C-h l`; this shows the last input that Emacs received from the OS. Copy-paste the part after `C-s`.

Comment: Clearly people who are trying to help are *guessing*, right and left. OP: Please edit your question to make it clearer. Describe the symptoms more completely, preferably using a step-by-step description, saying what you see and what you expected to see instead. And mention your platform, Emacs version, etc. And either start from `emacs -Q` (no init file) or mention whatever libraries etc. are needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that customising `search-exit-option` to `nil` will make isearch much more resilient to random inputs from the mouse.

The behaviour of isearch is now a bit odd - I can happily navigate around in emacs with the cursor keys and still be in isearch - but it does what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make C-s and M-% ignore mouse movement?

For just disabling accidental clicks, try this:

```
(dolist (k '([mouse-1] [down-mouse-1] [drag-mouse-1] [double-mouse-1] [triple-mouse-1]))
(global-unset-key k))
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked around it by disabling touchpad scrolling in the operating system settings (disabling it just within emacs didn't help). But this isn't ideal.